# Script genClusterPlugin.py failed with 403 Unauthorized

Tags: plugins, cluster-computing, websphere-liberty

I failed to generate a plugin file from a Liberty Cluster.
I use [this script](https://developer.ibm.com/assets/wasdev/#asset/scripts-jython-Generate_Cluster_Plugin).

```
Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: java.io.IOException: CWWKX0229E: Un problème est survenu avec les données d'identification de l'utilisateur fournies. Le serveur a répondu avec le code 401 et
 message 'Unauthorized'
        at com.ibm.ws.collective.repository.internal.ClusterManager.generateClusterPluginConfig(ClusterManager.java:320)
        at com.ibm.ws.collective.repository.internal.ClusterManagerMBeanImpl.generateClusterPluginConfig(ClusterManagerMBeanImpl.java:1216)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:95)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:55)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:507)
        at sun.reflect.misc.Trampoline.invoke(MethodUtil.java:83)
        at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor10.invoke(Unknown Source)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:55)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:507)
        at sun.reflect.misc.MethodUtil.invoke(MethodUtil.java:287)
        at com.sun.jmx.mbeanserver.StandardMBeanIntrospector.invokeM2(StandardMBeanIntrospector.java:124)
        at com.sun.jmx.mbeanserver.StandardMBeanIntrospector.invokeM2(StandardMBeanIntrospector.java:58)
        at com.sun.jmx.mbeanserver.MBeanIntrospector.invokeM(MBeanIntrospector.java:249)
        at com.sun.jmx.mbeanserver.PerInterface.invoke(PerInterface.java:150)
        at com.sun.jmx.mbeanserver.MBeanSupport.invoke(MBeanSupport.java:264)
        at javax.management.StandardMBean.invoke(StandardMBean.java:416)
        at com.sun.jmx.interceptor.DefaultMBeanServerInterceptor.invoke(DefaultMBeanServerInterceptor.java:831)
        ... 53 more
Caused by: java.io.IOException: CWWKX0229E: Un problème est survenu avec les données d'identification de l'utilisateur fournies. Le serveur a répondu avec le code 401 et le message 'Unauthorized'
        at com.ibm.ws.jmx.connector.client.rest.internal.RESTMBeanServerConnection.getBadCredentialsException(RESTMBeanServerConnection.java:1758)
        at com.ibm.ws.jmx.connector.client.rest.internal.RESTMBeanServerConnection.loadJMXServerInfo(RESTMBeanServerConnection.java:267)
        at com.ibm.ws.jmx.connector.client.rest.internal.RESTMBeanServerConnection.<init>(RESTMBeanServerConnection.java:161)
        at com.ibm.ws.jmx.connector.client.rest.internal.Connector.connect(Connector.java:371)
        at com.ibm.ws.jmx.connector.client.rest.internal.Connector.connect(Connector.java:112)
        at com.ibm.ws.collective.repository.internal.ClusterManagerMBeanImpl.getMBeanServerConnection(ClusterManagerMBeanImpl.java:1284)
        at com.ibm.ws.collective.repository.internal.ClusterManager.generateClusterPluginConfig(ClusterManager.java:314)
```

Answer (score 0):

The user/password you pass to this script need to be established in the application servers server.xml as someone with the administrator role.

One way to do that is the quickStartSecurity feature:

https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/was_beta_liberty/com.ibm.websphere.wlp.nd.multiplatform.doc/ae/twlp_sec_mapadmin.html

Comment: Thank you covener.
It does not work.
Connection to the collective controller works but connection beetween controller and members fails.